# Websphere liberty 19.0.0.9 could not find constructor for PolicyDataEngineImpl

Tags: cxf, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I trying to move from Websphere 9 to Liberty profile. Almost works fine but while i trying to call rest service i am getting exception:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [RestApplicationConfig] in application [DSI]: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not find constructor for class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl for args [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.bus.LibertyApplicationBus@70de7d28].
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:266)
    at [internal classes]
    at logback.RequestLoggerServletFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerServletFilter.java:59)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:241)
    ... 4 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5051)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:360)
    at [internal classes]
    at eu.unicredit.xframe.system.elf.logback.RequestLoggerServletFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerServletFilter.java:59)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not find constructor for class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl for args [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.bus.LibertyApplicationBus@70de7d28].
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:266)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:241)
    ... 4 more
```

Currently i have no idea how to solve this problem . 
I need help.

Best regards.
Rafał

Comment: I think i have found why this exception exist. Because two different class loaders exists. One of this rise CXF other LibertyContext. But now i do not know how to move cxf to correct class loader.

Comment: CXF is loaded by EquinoxClassLoader.

Comment: Ok i resolved problem. I have removed jaxrs feature from server.xml

Comment: are you using CXF API directly in your application? If not, it would be better to use the Liberty jaxrs-2.0 or 2.1 features instead of packaging your own version of CXF

Comment: The decision to use CXF not belongs to me. Maybe after migration i will change.